# How to Enable Logconfig for automatically created GKE Cluster & Service firewall rules using terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, firewall, terraform-provider-gcp

In Terraform I have enabled logging in firewall module and created 3 custom firewall rules in GCP and once terraform is applied logconfig is set to true. If I fire `gcloud compute firewall-rules list --format="table(name,logConfig)"` command my custom firewall rules shows LOG_CONFIG as 'enable': True whereas automatically created GKE cluster and service firewall rules shows as False.

Manually from console/command line I can update to true for GKE cluster and service firewall rules whereas via terraform I couldnt find solution. I have found the documentation on automatically created firewall rules in GCP https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/firewall-rules but dint found out enable log config automatically.

Could anyone provide me the solution.

Currently I am using this firewall rule and its enabling logconfig for my  custom rules.

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "default" {
  name    = "sample"
  network = "sample-network"
  project = "sample-project"
  enable_logging = "true"

  allow {
    protocol  = var.proto
    ports     = var.ports
  }
  
 log_config {
   metadata = "INCLUDE_ALL_METADATA"
  }

  source_tags   = var.sourceTags
  source_ranges = var.sourceRanges
  target_tags   = var.targetTags
}
```

Comment: Please provide the Terraform code you are using.

Comment: @MarkoE I have added the terraform code and edited the question. Using that module i can enable logs for firewall but for kubernetes firewall rules i couldn't found.

Comment: Can you tell me which resource are you trying to add firewall logs to? I.e. is it a GCP resource or something else?

Comment: @MarkoE I am trying to enable log config for automatically created firewall rules in GCP https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/firewall-rules. If you login to any cluster fire this command gcloud compute firewall-rules list --format="table(name,logConfig)" where you can see firewalls names starts with gke-something & k8s-something where logconfig will be false. I want to make it to true via terraform. Manually i can do it but via automation i dint find the solution.

Comment: Ok, so, the main question is: is there a resource in GCP Terraform provider which would let you do that?

Comment: @MarkoE: Correct I am looking for the same, For custom firewalls which was created by me I can enable logconfig using terraform as we have option https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_firewall

Whereas for GKE firewalls i dint find the option.

Answer (score 0):

I think the document you linked has the solution:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/firewall-rules

> If you would like more control over firewall behavior, you can create firewall rules with a higher priority. Firewall rules with a higher priority are applied before automatically created firewall rules.